# Merge Datetime Ranges

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I have been struggling to merge datetime ranges in oracle SQL/PLSQL (Database Standard Edition 11gR2).

I am trying to merge datetime ranges so that the following data

```
order_id    start_date_time         end_date_time
3933        04/02/2020 08:00:00     04/02/2020 12:00:00
3933        04/02/2020 13:30:00     04/02/2020 17:00:00
3933        04/02/2020 14:00:00     04/02/2020 19:00:00
3933        05/02/2020 13:40:12     05/02/2020 14:34:48
3933        05/02/2020 14:00:00     05/02/2020 18:55:12
3933        05/02/2020 14:49:48     05/02/2020 15:04:48
3933        06/02/2020 08:00:00     06/02/2020 12:00:00
3933        06/02/2020 13:30:00     06/02/2020 17:00:00
3933        06/02/2020 14:10:12     06/02/2020 18:49:48
3933        07/02/2020 08:00:00     07/02/2020 10:30:00
3933        07/02/2020 08:00:00     07/02/2020 12:00:00
3933        07/02/2020 13:30:00     07/02/2020 17:00:00
11919       14/05/2020 09:00:00     14/05/2020 17:00:00
11919       14/05/2020 09:00:00     14/05/2020 17:00:00
11919       14/05/2020 15:00:00     14/05/2020 16:30:00
11919       15/05/2020 08:40:12     15/05/2020 16:30:00
11919       15/05/2020 09:40:12     15/05/2020 16:30:00
11919       15/05/2020 10:15:00     15/05/2020 12:15:00
11919       15/05/2020 13:19:48     15/05/2020 16:00:00
11919       18/05/2020 08:49:48     18/05/2020 09:45:00
11919       18/05/2020 10:00:00     18/05/2020 17:00:00
11919       18/05/2020 10:00:00     18/05/2020 16:58:12
11919       18/05/2020 15:34:48     18/05/2020 16:10:12
11919       18/05/2020 16:30:00     18/05/2020 16:45:00
...         ...                     ...
```

would transform into the following result set

```
--after merge (this is the result I am seeking)
order_id    start_date_time         end_date_time
3933        04/02/2020 08:00:00     04/02/2020 12:00:00
3933        04/02/2020 13:30:00     04/02/2020 19:00:00
3933        05/02/2020 13:40:12     05/02/2020 18:55:12
3933        06/02/2020 08:00:00     06/02/2020 12:00:00
3933        06/02/2020 13:30:00     06/02/2020 18:49:48
3933        07/02/2020 08:00:00     07/02/2020 12:00:00
3933        07/02/2020 13:30:00     07/02/2020 17:00:00
11919       14/05/2020 09:00:00     14/05/2020 17:00:00
11919       15/05/2020 08:40:12     15/05/2020 16:30:00
11919       18/05/2020 08:49:48     18/05/2020 17:00:00
...         ...                     ...
```

The format of start_date_time and end_date_time is DAY/MONTH/YEAR HH24:MI:SS.

Any suggestion/solution on how to make that merge in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL?

I thought that was a trivial problem, however I was not able to find a solution on the internet yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those date/time columns need to be `DATE` data types. (`DATE`s do not have a format).Also, if you can provide the sample data as a CTE (or `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements), it will be easier to build and test potential solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
create table data(order_id number, start_date_time date, end_date_time date);
insert into data values (3933  ,'04/02/2020 08:00:00', '04/02/2020 12:00:00');
insert into data values (3933  ,'04/02/2020 13:30:00', '04/02/2020 17:00:00');
insert into data values (3933  ,'04/02/2020 14:00:00', '04/02/2020 19:00:00');
insert into data values (3933  ,'05/02/2020 13:40:12', '05/02/2020 14:34:48');
insert into data values (3933  ,'05/02/2020 14:00:00', '05/02/2020 18:55:12');
insert into data values (3933  ,'05/02/2020 14:49:48', '05/02/2020 15:04:48');
insert into data values (3933  ,'06/02/2020 08:00:00', '06/02/2020 12:00:00');
insert into data values (3933  ,'06/02/2020 13:30:00', '06/02/2020 17:00:00');
insert into data values (3933  ,'06/02/2020 14:10:12', '06/02/2020 18:49:48');
insert into data values (3933  ,'07/02/2020 08:00:00', '07/02/2020 10:30:00');
insert into data values (3933  ,'07/02/2020 08:00:00', '07/02/2020 12:00:00');
insert into data values (3933  ,'07/02/2020 13:30:00', '07/02/2020 17:00:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'14/05/2020 09:00:00', '14/05/2020 17:00:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'14/05/2020 09:00:00', '14/05/2020 17:00:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'14/05/2020 15:00:00', '14/05/2020 16:30:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'15/05/2020 08:40:12', '15/05/2020 16:30:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'15/05/2020 09:40:12', '15/05/2020 16:30:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'15/05/2020 10:15:00', '15/05/2020 12:15:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'15/05/2020 13:19:48', '15/05/2020 16:00:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'18/05/2020 08:49:48', '18/05/2020 09:45:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'18/05/2020 10:00:00', '18/05/2020 17:00:00');
insert into data values (11919 ,'18/05/2020 10:00:00', '18/05/2020 16:58:12');
insert into data values (11919 ,'18/05/2020 15:34:48', '18/05/2020 16:10:12');
insert into data values (11919 ,'18/05/2020 16:30:00', '18/05/2020 16:45:00');
commit;
```

Then with some magic:

```
select d1.order_id, d1.start_date_time, max(d2.end_date_time) as end_date_time
from data d1 join data d2
on (d1.order_id = d2.order_id and
(d1.start_date_time <= d2.end_date_time and d2.start_date_time <= d1.end_date_time))
group by d1.order_id, d1.start_date_time
intersect
select d1.order_id, min(d1.start_date_time), d2.end_date_time
from data d1 join data d2
on (d1.order_id = d2.order_id and
(d1.start_date_time <= d2.end_date_time and d2.start_date_time <= d1.end_date_time))
group by d1.order_id, d2.end_date_time
order by 1, 2, 3;

  ORDER_ID START_DATE_TIME     END_DATE_TIME      
---------- ------------------- -------------------
      3933 04/02/2020 08:00:00 04/02/2020 12:00:00
      3933 04/02/2020 13:30:00 04/02/2020 19:00:00
      3933 05/02/2020 13:40:12 05/02/2020 18:55:12
      3933 06/02/2020 08:00:00 06/02/2020 12:00:00
      3933 06/02/2020 13:30:00 06/02/2020 18:49:48
      3933 07/02/2020 08:00:00 07/02/2020 12:00:00
      3933 07/02/2020 13:30:00 07/02/2020 17:00:00
     11919 14/05/2020 09:00:00 14/05/2020 17:00:00
     11919 15/05/2020 08:40:12 15/05/2020 16:30:00
     11919 18/05/2020 08:49:48 18/05/2020 09:45:00
     11919 18/05/2020 10:00:00 18/05/2020 17:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you, @balazs-papp Also I would like to share the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238498/merge-datetime-ranges-oracle-sql-or-pl-sql)

Answer (score 3):

A method that does not require any self-joins and will only read the table once.

This is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705646/how-do-i-find-the-total-number-of-used-days-in-a-month/44707513#44707513) which contains an explanation of the code. All that has changed is to add `PARTITION BY order_id` to calculate the date ranges for each `order_id` and then to return the ranges (rather than total the values, as per the linked answer):

```sql
SELECT order_id,
       start_date_time,
       end_date_time
FROM   (
  SELECT order_id,
         LAG( dt ) OVER ( PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY dt ) AS start_date_time,
         dt AS end_date_time,
         start_end
  FROM   (
    SELECT order_id,
           dt,
           CASE SUM( value ) OVER ( PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM ) * value
             WHEN 1 THEN 'start'
             WHEN 0 THEN 'end'
           END AS start_end
    FROM   table_name
    UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( start_date_time AS 1, end_date_time AS -1 ) )
  )
  WHERE start_end IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE  start_end = 'end';
```

---

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to do row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY order_id
  ORDER     BY start_date_time
  MEASURES
    FIRST(start_date_time) AS start_date_time,
    MAX(end_date_time)     AS end_date_time
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN (overlapping_rows* last_row)
  DEFINE
    overlapping_rows AS NEXT(start_date_time) <= MAX(end_date_time)
)
```

Which, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  order_id NUMBER,
  start_date_time DATE,
  end_date_time DATE
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( order_id, start_date_time, end_date_time )
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-04 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-04 12:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-04 13:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-04 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-04 14:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-04 19:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-05 13:40:12', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-05 14:34:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-05 14:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-05 18:55:12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-05 14:49:48', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-05 15:04:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-06 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-06 12:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-06 13:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-06 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-06 14:10:12', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-06 18:49:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-07 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-07 10:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-07 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-07 12:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3933, TIMESTAMP '2020-02-07 13:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-07 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-14 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-14 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-14 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-14 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-14 15:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-14 16:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 08:40:12', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 16:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 09:40:12', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 16:30:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 10:15:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 12:15:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 13:19:48', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-15 16:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 08:49:48', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 09:45:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 10:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 17:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 10:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 16:58:12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 15:34:48', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 16:10:12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11919, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 16:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-05-18 16:45:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Both queries output:

> ```
> ORDER_ID | START_DATE_TIME     | END_DATE_TIME      
> -------: | :------------------ | :------------------
>     3933 | 2020-02-04 08:00:00 | 2020-02-04 12:00:00
>     3933 | 2020-02-04 13:30:00 | 2020-02-04 19:00:00
>     3933 | 2020-02-05 13:40:12 | 2020-02-05 18:55:12
>     3933 | 2020-02-06 08:00:00 | 2020-02-06 12:00:00
>     3933 | 2020-02-06 13:30:00 | 2020-02-06 18:49:48
>     3933 | 2020-02-07 08:00:00 | 2020-02-07 12:00:00
>     3933 | 2020-02-07 13:30:00 | 2020-02-07 17:00:00
>    11919 | 2020-05-14 09:00:00 | 2020-05-14 17:00:00
>    11919 | 2020-05-15 08:40:12 | 2020-05-15 16:30:00
>    11919 | 2020-05-18 08:49:48 | 2020-05-18 09:45:00
>    11919 | 2020-05-18 10:00:00 | 2020-05-18 17:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c04d59846a2b6e79fab0d856e651776)*